# Xcode 12 error in installing app -Failed to get FD to bundle executable

Tags: ios, swift, installation, ios-simulator, xcode12

My project is running fine in Xcode 11.3 but recently when I upgraded to Xcode 12 app is not getting installed in simulator and showing the error - Could not install at this time.
Failed to get FD to bundle executable....

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same problem.

Comment: This is what worked for me: I git cloned my project to a different folder, and I deleted the initial folder, and in Xcode I cleared the menu of most recently used project, and I opened that second project instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but still facing the same issue..not able to install app in any simulator.

Comment: Did you try creating a brand new app?

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly had the same problem, after years of work on the same project across several versions of Xcode and MacOS.
On Xcode 12.4 and MacOS 10.15.5, although everything was working fine, suddenly I got this error popup "Failed to get FD to bundle executable" while trying to Run the project on a(ny) Simulator.

I tried all the proposals I could find online, including changing the Executable Type (which had never changed) or clear the empty env vars defined in the Build settings (there weren't any). Uninstalling/reinstalling Xcode didn't help. Upgrading to MacOS 10.15.7 didn't either. Of course the Apple Support has been of no use at all (they replied with a few general FAQ links about how to use Simulator).

The only thing that worked for me was to **checkout the project in a different folder**...

The weird thing is, if I rename again my new folder to the initial folder name, it does the error again! It sounds to me like a MacOS bug and/or an Xcode bug.

Comment: your comment made me think that it had something to do with Xcode and cleaning the build folder solved it for me

Comment: I can add this piece of information to my own description of the problem:
it seems that the Endpoint Security system is force-killing my in-emulator app's process as soon as Xcode launches it. This may be related to the app's name, or the app bundle key name, or the app's contents... -- but it happened suddenly, after years of working fine (without Endpoint Security obviously).
Apple still doesn't have a response for me at the moment.

Comment: ahh strange yet interesting stuff

Answer (score 0):

```
Error running `xcrun simctl install 95F3A7B0-67B3-490E-B798-D1CBBF813B83 /Users/yakjuly/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.21.3.tar.app`: An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
Unable To Install “Expo Go”
Please try again later.
Failed to get FD to bundle executable at /Users/yakjuly/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95F3A7B0-67B3-490E-B798-D1CBBF813B83/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Nf39ZM/extracted/Exponent-2.21.3.tar.app/Expo Go
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
    Failed to get FD to bundle executable at /Users/yakjuly/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95F3A7B0-67B3-490E-B798-D1CBBF813B83/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Nf39ZM/extracted/Exponent-2.21.3.tar.app/Expo Go
```

I have this problem when I get started with react native.

The issue for me is the file in `/Users/yakjuly/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.21.3.tar.app` is broken. After I delete this file and re-run the command. it succeeds installing app in iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me was the following:

- close emulator
- clean project and build folder
  Shortcut: `Command+Shift+K`
  GUI: `Menu Bar -> Product -> Clean/Clean Build Folder`
- restart emulator

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The emulator's app process is being killed right away as soon as Xcode launches it.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 13.2.1**

The following steps helped me -

***1. Select simulator***

***2. Goto Device***

***3. Select -> Erase All Content and Settings...***

Hopefully, now you will be able to install and run the app on your simulator.